# How to run one feature file for Android and iOS

Tags: java, android, ios, cucumber, appium

I need to run test for Android and iOS. I have one feature file for 2 platforms, because steps are the same. And different steps definitions files and page object files, separate for Android and iOS. How I can run one feature file only for Android/iOS and together for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the different step definition files it look like it is impossible.

In my current framework, I'm passing system properties while executing maven command, and getting that properties in step definition(`isIos()` method checks device parameter i passed), after that i'm calling the actual method. In this framework, all step definitions are same for iOS and Android application which makes this method reasonable. But also for this method you should initialize all your page objects in the beginning of execution.(I'm not injecting dependencies, initializing them at the beginning, then injecting drivers to them in step definition files)

```
@Then("The user clicks add to basket button")
public void theUserClicksAddToBasketButton() {
    try {
        if (Hooks.isIos()) {
            iosHomePage.clickAddToBasket();
        } else {
            androidHomePage.clickAddToBasket();
        }
        logger.info("The user clicked add to basket button");
    } catch (Throwable err) {
        logger.fatal("The user can not clicks add to basket button");
        Assert.fail("ERROR : " + "The user can not clicks add to basket button" + err);
    }
}
```